# How to start an activity which calls a method from a different class?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an activity which transfer a string datatype to another activity which then uses that string and calls a method from another class which returns a string. I want to use that method to display the string in the current activity.

So visually it goes (activity 1) -- string--> (activity 2). Activity 2 uses that string to call a method in a different java class which returns a type string which i want to display on the screen along with a few buttons.

So some pseudo code:

say The method in a different java class is:

```
public static String getStringexample(String n) {
return "hello" + " " + n;
}
```

and my activity class is:

```
public class manage extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContainerView(R.layout.activity_manage);

       Intent intent = getIntent();
       String example = intent.getExtras().getString("intentid");
```

i'm lost after this..not sure how to use what i got from the intent to display it on the screen in java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information between activities is passed in 'extras'. That is just a collection of string keys and values.

Both sides need to use the same keys, so define static final strings with they keys that your destination activity expects.

Then read the values from the extras using the key and go from there:

```
public class DestinationActivity extends Activity {

    // let your callers know how to pass you the information you need
    public static final String EXTRA_N = "n";

    private TextView resultText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_destination);

        resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultText);

        // get the information you was passed
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String n = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_N);

        // do your transformation using the other class
        String example = DifferentClass.getStringexample(n);

        // display the transformed string
        resultText.setText(example);    
    }

    // ... 
}
```

The calling activity sends the information like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DestinationActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(DestinationActivity.EXTRA_N, "foo");
startActivity(intent);
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can start activity as

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

Then return to first activity from second activity

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",yourdata);
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

In your first activity you will get result by using below code

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (requestCode == 1) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
    }
    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        //Write your code if there's no result
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I don't want to return to the first activity though. I want the second activity to display the string using the java method, but i'd be adding a few other things to the new activity as well.